# How to store dashboard definitions in oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

I am creating a system for displaying dashboards. A dashboard is made up of a number of dashlets of different types e.g. a trend, a histogram, a spiderplot etc.
Currently I define each dashlet as a row within an oracle table. My dilemma is as follows. Each type of dashlet has a different set of parameters such as line color, y axis title, maximum y etc. Up to now I have been creating a different column for each parameter but this means that I have a very large number of columns and many of the columns are not relevant for a particular dashlet and are left empty. I have now tried using a single column called definitions which contains information defining the characteristics of the dashlet. Example below.
ytitle: Count|
linecolor: Yellow|
linethickness: 12|
.....

The problem with this is that if you mis-spell an item the program will fail at runtime. 
What is the best way to tackle this problem.

Comment: 1.) Create a table with columns for all possible dashlet parameters. The records of this table will any instantiation of a dashlet parameter set. In general this there will be (potentially many) `NULL`values in each record. 2.) Create another table that for each dashlet type holds the valid parameters. This way you associate dashlets with supported params only once and you can test exhaustively For each instance just pass values. Choose a syntax as simple as you see fit.

Comment: ... Another option is to invest in catching run-time failures of dashlet instantiations: you cannot completely evade that step because you have to safeguard against illegal/misspelt parameter values anyway.

Comment: How many dashlets and attributes are there?  If it's just 50, I'd say stick with a table.  If it's over 1000 then you'll need something like the Entity Attribute Value pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can create table, let's say t_parameters, where parameter name(ytitle,linecolor) will be primary or unique key. Then you can create a foreign key on your parameter_name column which is in your definition table (the one storing assingment: ytitle Count,etc...)

Now if you want to ensure that also parameter value is from exact list, you can do the same by creating table of parameter values and creating unique key and then foreign key in definition table.

Then if you need it to be more advanced and check which parameter can be of which values you can create lookup table having columns parameter_name,parameter_value like:

linecolor; yellow

linecolor; red

Ytitle; sum

Ytitle; count

This is one way how to ensure reference integrity.

Best practice would be to set in t_parameter for parameter_name an numeric id and made this to be PK and reference these in lookup tables.